# Проблемы с мышкой в Sublime Text 2

Tags: linux, sublime-text

Редактор не реагирует на нажатия мышки в рабочей области. ЛКМ, ПКМ, выделение текста, etc. — не работает. Работает только скроллинг колёсиком. Вне рабочей области (панель инструментов) всё нормально.

Переустановка не помогает. 
Система: Linux — OpenSUSE 12.2, WM — Awesome.

Comment: Эта штука под линукс очень криво сделана.

Comment: В Ubuntu работает как часы!

Comment: А drag-drop внутри текста работает?

Comment: Сейчас нет возможности проверить.

Comment: @mikillskegg Archlinux, Awesome. Около года полёт нормальный.
dnd внутри текста не работает. А он нужен? Я уж и забыл почти, что такое мышь.

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в Awesome. Испытайте в другом WM.

Comment: Та же самая история. Система openSUSE 12.2, KDE 4.

Comment: В общем я разобрался. Проблема в OpenSUSE, а точнее в одной из библиотек. Откат до предыдущей версии решает проблему.

Comment: Пипитарное ПО, что вы хотели-то?

Comment: @drdaeman, шоб производители отрабатывали деньги, которые они собирают с пользователей )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно в консоли скомандовать

> export LC_NUMERIC=C

Нашел [здесь](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8543). Но очевидно, что это не самое приятное решение потому, что эту команду нужно выполнять всегда перед запуском sublime.

Можете попробовать написать скрипт, который будет сначала выполнять команду выше а потом запускать sublime.

Comment: А команду под root вводить? Пробовал по всякому, все равно не работает.

Т.е. я пишу в консоли export LC_NUMERIC=C, потом запускаю Sublime. 

Answer (score 0):

Я помучился с такой фишкой: старый ноут с тачскрином (touchscreen), который сломался и мешал пользоваться ноутом, поэтому после включения всегда вводилась строка:

```
xinput disable "Wacom ISDv4 93 Finger touch"
```

После апгрейда Sublime Text 2 до билда 3103 в программе не работал скролл (scroll) мышки, пока не вбивалась эта самая строчка! Вычислить оказалось не просто :))

Linux version 3.16.0-38-generic (buildd@allspice) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)